# Updating specific column of all my rows in database using check boxes on clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So, When i select the approve or deny button for all the four rows and click submit button then it should update my database column status as approved or denied as per the selection and also according to the job name and desired job in my table, I am a newbie in php Pls help...

Database -->**projectdb**

Table -->**jobdetails**

```
no(AI)|jobname|desiredjob|jobexpectations|req1|req2|req3|req4|req5|status.
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
//connect to the server
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'guest', 'guest'); 
if (!$link) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

//connect to the database
mysql_select_db('projectdb'); 

//query the database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobdetails WHERE status='In Progress...'");

//fetch the results / convert results into an array
$jobname=array();
$desiredjob=array();
$jobexpectations=array();
$req1=array();
$req2=array();
$req3=array();
$req4=array();
$req5=array();
    WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $jobname[] = $rows['jobname'];
        $desiredjob[] = $rows['desiredjob'];
        $jobexpectations[] = $rows['jobexpectations'];
        $req1[] = $rows['req1'];
        $req2[] = $rows['req2'];
        $req3[] = $rows['req3'];
        $req4[] = $rows['req4'];
        $req5[] = $rows['req5']; 
    }
?>


<form method="post" action="">
  <tr id="1">

    <td class="type-info" style="width:10%"><?=$jobname[0]?><a class="anchorjs-link" href="#h3.-bootstrap-heading"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:10%"><?=$desiredjob[0]?><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:35%"><?=$jobexpectations[0]?><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:35%"><ul><li><?=$req1[0]?></li><li><?=$req2[0]?></li><li><?=$req3[0]?></li><li><?=$req4[0]?></li><li><?=$req5[0]?></li></ul><br></br></td>          
      <td class="type-info" style="width:5%"><input type="checkbox"  value="Approved" id="status"> Approve</label></div><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:5%"><input type="checkbox"  value="Denied" id = "status"> Deny</label></div><br></br></td>
    </tr>
  <tr id ="2">
      <td class="type-info" style="width:10%"><?=$jobname[1]?><a class="anchorjs-link" href="#h3.-bootstrap-heading"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:10%"><?=$desiredjob[1]?><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:35%"><?=$jobexpectations[1]?><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:35%"><ul><li><?=$req1[1]?></li><li><?=$req2[1]?></li><li><?=$req3[1]?></li><li><?=$req4[1]?></li><li><?=$req5[1]?></li></ul><br></br></td>

      <td class="type-info" style="width:5%"><input type="checkbox" value="Approved" name="status" id="status"> Approve</label></div><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:5%"><input type="checkbox" value="Denied" name="status" id = "status"> Deny</label></div><br></br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
    <td class="type-info" style="width:10%"><?=$jobname[2]?><a class="anchorjs-link" href="#h3.-bootstrap-heading"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:10%"><?=$desiredjob[2]?><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:35%"><?=$jobexpectations[2]?><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:35%"><ul><li><?=$req1[2]?></li><li><?=$req2[2]?></li><li><?=$req3[2]?></li><li><?=$req4[2]?></li><li><?=$req5[2]?></li></ul><br></br></td>          
      <td class="type-info" style="width:5%"><input type="checkbox"  value="Approved" id="status"> Approve</label></div><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:5%"><input type="checkbox"  value="Denied" id = "status"> Deny</label></div><br></br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
    <td class="type-info"><?=$jobname[3]?><a class="anchorjs-link" href="#h3.-bootstrap-heading"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></td>
      <td class="type-info"><?=$desiredjob[3]?><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info"><?=$jobexpectations[3]?><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info"><ul><li><?=$req1[3]?></li><li><?=$req2[3]?></li><li><?=$req3[3]?></li><li><?=$req4[3]?></li><li><?=$req5[3]?></li></ul><br></br></td>          
      <td class="type-info" style="width:5%"><input type="checkbox"  value="Approved" id="status"> Approve</label></div><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:5%"><input type="checkbox"  value="Denied" id = "status"> Deny</label></div><br></br></td>
      <td class="type-info" style="width:5%"><button type="submit" name="submit" class="styled-button-2" onClick="myFunction()" value="submit">Confirm</button></td>
    </td>
    </tr>
</body>
</table>
```

Comment: *Question Is Unclear*

Comment: And, What if you select `Approved` & `Denied` Checkbox together for that particular row. ? *Question Is Unclear*

Comment: Only one should be selected, pls help on this I am stuck

Comment: Hey @Aadityan : You didn't responded back.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select one `checkbox` for one particular row.

[**NOTE** : Your script is at risk for **SQL Injection Attacks**. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`]

```
<?php
//connect to the server
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'guest', 'guest'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

//connect to the database
mysql_select_db('projectdb'); 
?>


    <form method="post" action="somePage.php">
        <table>
            <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobdetails WHERE status='In Progress...'");
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {?>
            <tr id="<?=$rows['no']?>">
                <td class="type-info" style="width:10%">
                    <?=$rows['jobname']?>
                    <a class="anchorjs-link" href="#h3.-bootstrap-heading">
                        <span class="anchorjs-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="type-info" style="width:10%"><?=$rows['desiredjob']?><br></br></td>
                <td class="type-info" style="width:35%"><?=$rows['jobexpectations']?><br></br></td>
                <td class="type-info" style="width:35%">
                    <ul>
                        <li><?=$req1['req1']?></li>
                        <li><?=$req2['req2']?></li>
                        <li><?=$req3['req3']?></li>
                        <li><?=$req4['req4']?></li>
                        <li><?=$req5['req5']?></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br></br>
                </td>          
                <td class="type-info" style="width:5%">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="<?=$rows['no']?>"><label> Approve</label><br></br>
                </td>
                <td class="type-info" style="width:5%">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="deny[]" value="<?=$rows['no']?>"><label> Deny</label>
                    <br></br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**somePage.php**

```
<?php

// Approved Rows
$countApprove = sizeof($_POST['approve']);
for($i=0;$i<$countApprove;$i++)
{
        $id = $approve[$i];
        mysql_query("UPDATE jobdetails SET status='Approved' WHERE no='$id'");
}

// Denied Rows
$countDeny = sizeof($_POST['deny']);
for($i=0;$i<$countDeny;$i++)
{
        $id = $deny[$i];
        mysql_query("UPDATE jobdetails SET status='Denied' WHERE no='$id'");
}
?>
```